# Android interaction and input systems for people with severe tremors

Tags: keyboard, gboard, accessibility, input-methods, text-input

I wonder whether any work has been done in Android to support people with severe hand tremors in the accessibility settings.

I was thinking, the device could be configured, so that touching several times something, such as an app icon, would just move the focus of where the user wanted to select, whereas resting the hand would finally click.

Is this mode of interaction available in Android?

What version of Android supports this?

How can I configure my Android system for interaction by a person with hand tremors?

Eventually, a keyboard must be available that follows this principle as well.

Thank you for your support.

Thank you for your replies.

Thanks.